# ModuleNotFoundError: No moudle name <name> in docker python

Tags: python, docker, containers

I have two python files `my_script.py` `test.py` with below content.

**my_script.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import sys

sys.path.append("/home/user/test")
import test as count

data = count.function()
print(data)
```

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time

def function():
        print("This is function")
        return "test"
```

When I execute `my_script.py`, I get the following result:

```
This is function
test
```

I created docker image of `my_script.py` using Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ADD my_script.py /

CMD [ "python3", "./my_script.py" ]
```

But when I am running its container, I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./my_script.py", line 13, in <module>
    import test as count
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test'
```

Initially I thought the container will look for test.py automatically and will perform its function but its not. How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: You should properly package and install your modules, instead of messing with `sys.path` manually.

Comment: @NilsWerner You mean to say that I should create a docker for test.py too. Then it will work.?

Comment: No, [create a `setup.py`](https://packaging.python.org/) and `pip install -e <dir>` it in your `Dockerfile`

Comment: @NilsWerner For his test creating a fully blown pip module is probably a tad bit overkill...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I'll add a bit more clarification based on comments below.
Wherever your files are on your local system has no relation to where they will be inside your docker container.

Hence, before you can run stuff in a container (which is essentially "another server" of sorts) you need to copy files from your local machine into the container.

To achieve what you want to achieve your `Dockerfile` needs to look like:

```
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir -p /home/user/test
ADD my_script.py /home/user/test/
ADD test.py /home/user/test/

CMD [ "python3", "/home/user/test/my_script.py" ]
```

And then you can remove your path mangling from your script.

So that final `my_script.py` would look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import sys
import test as count

data = count.function()
print(data)
```

Comment: In docker? By what? `FROM python:3` doesn't have `/home/user/test` in it I'm 99% sure about it.

Comment: Outside of fixing this particular scenario... What is it that you're trying to achieve by separating those 2 files?

Comment: i.e. why not `ADD` both files to the same dir and then just do `import test as count` ?

Comment: Both files are in same directory which is /home/user/test. I just want to know if we have two python code which are importing modules from each other then how can we deal with this in docker side.

Comment: Same as anywhere else. If you add both files to docker container, to the _same_ directory, you a) don't need path amendment, b) can just import.

Comment: Okay can you explain how can I add both files to a docker container.

Comment: Just one question. Where these folders are created in docker.?